# OfficeOpenXml remove HyperLink

Tags: excel, powershell, epplus

Im use Powershell module "ImportExcel" for generating xlsx report.
Some string, as "openstack-9cea5509-ed06-4301-b9e2-10f742e8c174:8", add in cell as HyperLink.
I cant remove HyperLink, next method not work:

```
$d = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        HLUNID = "String11`nString22"
        HostID = "String33`nStrong44"
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        HLUNID = "String55`nString552"
        HostID = "openstack-9cea5509-ed06-4301-b9e2-10f742e8c174:8"
    }
)

Export-Excel -Path "out1.xlsx" -InputObject $d -WorksheetName 'Luns' -AutoNameRange
$Excel = Open-ExcelPackage -Path "out1.xlsx"
$Excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Luns'].Cells['HostID'] | Set-ExcelRange -ResetFont
$Excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Luns'].Cells[3,2].HyperLink = ''
Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $Excel
```

String steel stay clickable:
[Image - "Clickable cell"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx3Nz.png)

Next method is not exist:

```
$Excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Luns'].Cells[3,2].HyperLink.Remove()
$Excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Luns'].Cells[3,2].HyperLink.Dispose()
```

Please, give me another method for delete HyperLynk.

Comment: A hyperlink in Excel is usually blue underlined. This does not seem to be a hyperlink, but something your Excel does. It shows the actual filename in a tooltip, not an url.

Comment: Underlined and Blue color im change by this command: $Excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Luns'].Cells['HostID'] | Set-ExcelRange -ResetFont. Initially this cell has been Blue and Underlined.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the hyperlink $null

```
$Excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Luns'].Cells[3,2].HyperLink = $null
```

It will remove the hyperlink, but won't touch the formatting.

Have a read about the method and the functions to manage hyperlink I have proposed to be included into the module.
[How to make Excel hyperlinks with PowerShell?](https://www.bronowski.it/blog/2021/01/how-to-make-excel-hyperlinks-using-powershell/)